# How can I limit how much is shown in WebView?

Tags: android, eclipse, webview, viewport

I am working on an application that uses WebView to display multiple documents that are hosted online.  Preferably, I'd like to have it set so that no scrolling is required.  Instead, a "Next" button could be used to bring up a "new page" that would be a continuation of the text.

For example, one of the documents this application would read can be found at

http://www.missionstclare.com/english/May/whole/morning/24m.html

Is there a way to easily break the document up so that it only shows what would fit in the viewport?

Note: This is for an android app using eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy, out-of-the-box way to do it.

If you are running the server, then you can check for the user agent and serve a smaller page to the device.

If you are not, you will need to use an URLConnection, retrieve the text, parse it, and display chunks of it in the WebView.